# Does self.close actually kill the web worker thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

See this example:

```js
// CLOSEWORKER.JS:

self.postMessage('foo');
self.close();
self.postMessage('bar');
setTimeout(() => self.postMessage('baz'), 0);

// MAIN.JS:

const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(data);
```

Even if I have invoked `self.close()`,the next line `self.postMessage('bar');` still executed and log 'bar'.I can't understand that since the close method should just kill the worker thread right after being called.

Also ,see another example:

```js
TERMINATEWORKER.JS:

self.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(data);

MAIN.JS:

const worker = new Worker('./worker.js');
setTimeout(() => {
 worker.postMessage('foo');
 worker.terminate();
 worker.postMessage('bar');
 setTimeout(() => worker.postMessage('baz'), 0);
}, 1000)
```

When using the `terminate` method instead of the `close` method, the code executed as I expected. It just logs 'foo', no-log any other thing, which suggests that the thread has been killed right after calling the `terminate` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`WorkerGlobalScope.close()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#close-a-worker) when called discards any tasks that have been scheduled and sets the [`closing`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#dom-workerglobalscope-closing) flag of the WorkerGlobalScope, effectively preventing any new task to get queued.

**However, it doesn't stop the execution of the *current* task.**

So indeed, in your first example, it will run the current script until its end and still execute the `self.postMessage('bar')` operation, that your main thread will be able to handle.

[`Worker.terminate()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#terminate-a-worker) on the other hand will also "[a]bort the script currently running in the worker."

Comment: "However, it doesn't stop the execution of the current task." Does this mean that it will still finish all the sync tasks of the current execution stack but no those tasks which are in the callback queue (such as timeout callback) ?

Comment: Yes, it means that the current task (here the current JS job) will get executed to its end. Even the `setTimeout` call will itself get called, however all tasks that were queued will get discarded, and the task that should have been queued internally by setTimeout will also get discared.

Comment: Also not that even if it's a bit unclear in the specs, queued microtasks will also get executed.

Comment: "queued microtasks will also get executed", this means If I write `Promise.resolve(1).then( val => { console.log(val)} )` at the last line of the code,the then callback will executes?

Comment: And there is no way for us to execute one line code inside the worker.js and immediately close the worker thread ? `terminate` method can immediately close it but we can only invoke it from outside.

Comment: Yes, the Promise reaction will get called, even if queued after the `close()` call. `terminate()` **does not** close it immediately either. It's just that in the `terminate()` case you hadn't anything else going on in the *current task* (which consisted only in setting the flag and emptying the queues. And you can stop the execution of the current job by `throw`ing there, but yes, if there were queued micro-tasks, these will get executed anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232495/discussion-between-chor-and-kaiido).

Comment: I have a last question. Is the `close` method the same as `terminate` method for SharedWorker? Just learn from "JavaScript professional 4th" which says that "self.close() is the counterpart to worker.terminate(). It is used to immediately terminate the worker. No opportunity for cleanup is afforded to the worker; the script is abruptly ended" So it seems that the `close` method of SharedWorker is difference from that of DedicatedWorker (which we have dicussed above) ?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in my previous comment, [terminate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#terminate-a-worker) **does** "[a]bort the script currently running in the worker." And SharedWorkerGlobalScope's `close()` method calls the same algorithm as DedicatedWorker's, and their `worker.terminate()` are exactly the same method.

Comment: I‘m confused because the book says "Importantly, there is no way to programmatically terminate a shared worker. You will notice that the `terminate()` method is absent from the SharedWorker object."